# Trying to create a rewrite rule in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a url that looks like this

www.myurl.com/page/blog

which works fine with my current rewrite rule. But when I try to append append additional query stings to it it doesn't work.

www.myurl.com/page/blog?group=2

Is there something I could add to my rewrite rule that will make it catch all additional query strings?

This is my current rule:

```
 RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `[QSA]` flag to pass through the original query string params i.e.

> RewriteRule ^page/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]